# ErrorCode<ERRPS013>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Operation was aborted because user selected not to enable Cache with secondaries

Tags: windows-7, appfabric

I get this error when running Start/Stop/Restart-CacheCluster commands in Caching Administration Windows PowerShell console:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:Operation was aborted because
>   user selected not to enable Cache with secondaries.

What am I missing here? Microsoft help does not list this error code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921008%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).
Running v.1.1 of AppFabric on Windows7 x64 machine.

**EDIT:** I have a single host, but am running in cache cluster. Also this set-up used to work a couple of days before, but unfortunately can't tell what actions exactly led to it stopping working.

Answer (score 0):

The secondaries feature of the caching mechanism has to do with High Availability for the cache cluster.  Based on your description it looks like you only have a single host, therefore you don't actually have a cache cluster.  What if you try the start/stop/restart-cachehost commands instead?

Also, are you sure you have actually setup a cache-cluster and have used the use-cluster command before trying to issue a command?

BTW, v1.2 is also out which may improve some of the messages and functionality, it did for me.

Comment: If I tried start/stop/restart-cachehost - I get completely the same exception as with cluster. Although you are right regarding single host. I haven't used "use-cluster" command, but assume it was used by configuration tool. When I tried using it manually - I got Use-CacheCluster : Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Utility.GetInstallPathFromRegistry()'. Therefore I tried reinstalling 1.1 version. Which for some reasons also did not work. So ended up in using v1.0. Can't find v1.2 - is it available publicly?